# Integrate BigQuery SubPub and Cloud Functions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-signin

I'm in a project the we need to use BigQuery, PubSub, Logs explorer and Cloud Functions.

The project:

Every time certain event occurs (like an user accepting cookies), a system inserts a new query into BigQuery with a lot of columns (params) like: utm_source, utm_medium, consent_cookies, etc...

Once I have this new query in my table I need to read the columns and get the values to use in a cloud function.

In the cloud function I want to use those values to make api calls.

What I manage to do so far:

I created a log routing sink that filter the new entries and send the log to my PubSub topic.

Where I'm stuck:

I want to create a Cloud function that triggers every time a new log comes in and in that function I want to access the information that is contained in the log, such as utm_source, utm_medium, consent_cookies, etc... And use values to make api calls.

Anyone can help me? Many MANY thanks in advance!

I made a project to illustrate the flow:

1. Insert to table:
   [image]

2.From this insertion create a sink in logging: (filtering)
[image]

3. Now every time I create a new query it goes to PUB/SUB i get the log of the query
   [image]

4. What I want to do is to trigger a function on this topic and use the values I have in the query to do operations like call api etc...

So far I was able to write this code:

```
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Import the Google Cloud client library
  const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

  async function queryDb() {
    
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();

   
    const sqlQuery = `SELECT *  FROM \`mydatatable\``;

    const options = {
      query: sqlQuery,
      location: "europe-west3",
    };

    // Run the query
    const [rows] = await bigqueryClient.query(options);

    rows.forEach((row) => {
      const username = row.user_name;
    });
  }

  queryDb();
}

main();
```

Now I'm again stuck, Idont know how to get the correct query from the sink I created and use the info to make my calls...

Comment: (Me again :) ) Do you have the data details in the logs? If not, why the process that write into BigQuery doesn't write into PubSub also with the correct parameters?

Comment: Heyy @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you so much for your time and patience! I added all the steps with images for a better understanding what I'm trying to do

Comment: Ok, it's clear. I can reproduce now and propose your a piece of code. What's your preferred language (if I can, I will make the example with it)

Comment: I’m used to work with node.js. Thank you so much! Python wouldn’t be a problem, which one is best for you hero! Thanks

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've manage to write some code, I'm i the right path?  Merci beaucoup!

Comment: I just realize that if I'm able to read the data and extract what I want from the message that the sink sends to pubsub would be easier, is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: NodeJS is the less known language for me, but I achieve this. You don't have to query BigQuery, because you already have the values in the log. Tell me if my answer fit your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions to call your Cloud Functions from a PubSub message

- HTTP Functions: You can set up a HTTP call. Create your Cloud Function in trigger-http, and create a push subscription on your PubSub topic to call the Cloud Functions. Don't forget to add security (make your function private and enable security on PubSub) because your function is publicly accessible
- Background functions: You can bind directly your Cloud Functions to PubSub topic. A subscription is automatically created and linked to the Cloud Functions. The security is built-in.

And, because you have 2 types of functions, you have 2 different function signatures. I provide you both, the processing is the (quite) same.

```
function extractQuery(pubSubMessage){
    // Decide base64 the PubSub message
    let logData = Buffer.from(pubSubMessage, 'base64').toString();
    // Convert it in JSON
    let logMessage= JSON.parse(logData)
    // Extract the query from the log entry
    let query = logMessage.protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.query

    console.log(query)
    return query
}

// For HTTP functions
exports.bigqueryQueryInLog = (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
    const query = extractQuery(req.body.message.data)

    res.status(200).send(query);
}

// For Background functions
exports.bigqueryQueryInLogTopic = (message, context) => {
    extractQuery(message.data)
};
```

The `query` logged is the `insert into...` that you have in your log entry. Then, you have to parse your SQL request to extract the part that you want.

Comment: Dear @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks to you I was able to deploy the func and now I have access to the data, It's possible from the same func make api calls? Merci, you helped me tellment!

Comment: Now under the func log I can see that the values I need are under textPayload. Like so:
textPayload: "VALUES ("id","utm"," cookies"," fbp ","2021-01-05",TRUE )",  is not a key pair, between my filed and value from bigQuery... There is any way to have that going? My project is to use the fields to make an api call to  fb conversion Api, that's why I need the values, if they are in this format the only way to access is through regular expressions? Thanks again for your time and patience! I'm learning a lot from you!

Comment: ```function facebookApiCall(req,res){
 var request = require('request');
 var options = {
 'method': 'POST',
 'url': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0//events',
 'headers': {
  },
  formData: {
    'data': '[ { "event_name": "postman",  "event_time": 1610016563,"user_data": { "em": "7b17fb0bd173f6616516451114dcss3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068","ph": null}, "custom_data": {"currency": "EUR",     "value": "142.52" } }]',
    'access_token': ''"
  }
};request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  return console.log(response.body);
});}```

Comment: Yes, it's not a keypair, it's the SQL request. You have to parse them manually. I agree it's not very safe and efficient.

Comment: Can I parse them in the same function? Can you suggest another approach? I'm super confuse with this project and with GCP, so I really don't know how to procced

Comment: If you design your pipeline by using logs, you need to perform reverse engineering to read the logs and extract the value. A better design is to have a fork: 1 branch insert the data into BigQuery, another branch publish a message into PubSub. But you have to change your pipeline before writing into BigQuery and I don't know if you can.

Comment: I don't think I can but I'll let my superior know, thank you again for all your help, you're very kind!